# Java - Write a condition for a classes method that ensures only some items of a HashMap can be used.

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap, filtering, conditional-statements

Okay, so I have a class called WeaponList that contains a static HashMap of type `<String, Ranged>` (Ranged is another class) The Ranged class also extends another class called Weapon.

Then I have another class called Scout. A Scout is a composition of a Weapon (which Ranged extends remember) and an int of points. I should also point out that the ScoutSquad class is an aggregation of Scouts, with get and set methods.

So in the main program, when you instaniate a Scout Object the default Ranged weapon of each Scout is a "Bolt Pistol" and the default points is 13.

Now in the Scout class theres an option to upgrade your Ranged weapon via the method rangedUpgrade(Ranged ranged). So in the main program using this line of code: `scouts.getScout(5).rangedUpgrade(WeaponList.getRanged("Shotgun"));` succesfully upgrades the Scout at index 5, and displays the new Weapon and the scouts new points (as each Weapon has points associated with it)

However currently the Scout can upgrade to any Ranged weapon in the WeaponList classes HashMap. I would like it so the Scout can only upgrade to certain Ranged weapons in the HashMap. I've already tried setting conditions with if statements, but with no success so far. (Lines 27 - 35 of the Scout class)

I'll provide code for all the relavant classes, and hope that someone can help with this.

Thanks.

WeaponList Class

```
package armoury1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import troops.scouts.Scout;

public class WeaponList
{
    static Map<String, Ranged> rangedlist = new HashMap<String, Ranged>()
    {{          
        put("Bolter", new Ranged2H("Bolter", 1));
        put("Bolt Pistol", new Ranged("Bolt Pistol", 1));
        put("Flamer", new Ranged2H("Flamer", 1));
        put("Meltagun", new Ranged2H("Meltagun", 1));
        put("Plasma Gun", new Ranged2H("Plasma Gun", 1));
        put("Plasma Pistol", new Ranged("Plasma Pistol", 10));
        put("Shotgun", new Ranged2H("Shotgun", 10));
        put("Sniper Rifle", new Ranged2H("Sniper Rifle", 5));

        put("Assault Cannon", new Ranged2H("Assault Cannon", 10));
        put("Cyclone Missle Launcher", new Ranged2H("Cyclone Missle Launcher", 10));
        put("Heavy Bolter", new Ranged2H("Heavy Bolter", 10));
        put("Heavy Flamer", new Ranged2H("Heavy Flamer", 10));
        put("Assault Cannon", new Ranged2H("Lascannon", 10));
        put("Missle Launcher", new Ranged2H("Missle Launcher", 10));
        put("Multi Melta", new Ranged2H("Multi Melta", 10));
        put("Plasma Cannon", new Ranged2H("Plasma Cannon", 10));

    }};

    public static Ranged getRanged(String index)
    {       
        return rangedlist.get(index);   
    }

    public static Map<String, Ranged> getRangedList()
    {           
        return rangedlist;
    }
}
```

Scout Class

```
package troops.scouts;

import armoury.Wargear;
import armoury1.Melee;
import armoury1.Ranged;
import armoury1.Weapon;
import armoury1.WeaponList;

public class Scout
{
    private Weapon ranged, melee;
    private int points;

    //DEFAULT SCOUT
    public Scout() 
    {       
        ranged = new Ranged("Bolt Pistol", 0);
        melee = new Melee("Close Combat Weapon", 0);

        points = 13; 
        points = points + ranged.getWeaponPoints() + melee.getWeaponPoints();

    }

    public void rangedUpgrade(Ranged ranged)
    {       
        if (ranged.equals(WeaponList.getRanged("Shotgun")));
        {       
            this.ranged = ranged; 
            points = points + ranged.getWeaponPoints();
        }   


        else 
            System.out.println("Can not have this weapon");
    }   

    public void meleeUpgrade(Melee melee) 
    {
        this.melee = melee; 
        points = points + melee.getWeaponPoints();
    }

    public Weapon getRangedUpgrade()
    {
        return ranged;
    }

    public Weapon getMeleeUpgrade()
    {
        return melee;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "|| " + "Ranged Weapon: " + ranged + " || " + "Melee Weapon: " + melee + " || " + "Points: " + points;
    }
}
```

Main Program

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import armoury1.Melee;
import armoury1.Ranged;
import armoury1.Weapon;
import armoury1.WeaponList;
import troops.scouts.Scout;
import troops.scouts.ScoutSergeant;
import troops.scouts.ScoutSquad;

public class ArmyBuilderDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {       
        ScoutSquad scouts = new ScoutSquad("Squad 1");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the squad size: ");
        int size = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            scouts.addScout(new Scout());

        System.out.println(scouts.getScoutSquad());

        scouts.getScout(5).rangedUpgrade(WeaponList.getRanged("Shotgun"));
        scouts.getScout(5).meleeUpgrade(WeaponList.getMelee(3));

        System.out.println(scouts.getScoutSquad());

      input.close();
    }   
}
```

Ranged Class (extends Weapon)

```
package armoury1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import troops.scouts.Scout;

public class Ranged extends Weapon 
{       
    public Ranged(String name, int points) 
    {       
        super(name, points);
    }   
}
```

Comment: what is the question??? remember there is no such ***Lines 27 - 35*** for us here....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I would like it so the Scout can only upgrade to certain Ranged weapons in the HashMap, and isn't able to upgrade to all of them. So I need to condition in the upgradeRanged method of the Scout class

Comment: Please provide the source code of Ranged class.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala Okay just a second.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala You should know that the Ranged class isn't yet fully implemented, I just want the basics to work first.

Comment: It could be easily solved if you have attribute like weaponLevel so lets say starting weapons have level 1 and upgraded have 2, then you can limit it so than weapon from 1 can only go to level 2, level 2 to 3 ... I think you got the point.

Comment: What about your attempted solution doesn't work? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Radiodef It turns out i forgot to implement the equals method and there was a minor error causing it to not work. A silly mistake.

Comment: @FilipRistic Thanks for the idea, but I don't think that would be suitable for this program. I appreciate your input though

Comment: It's not clear to me that you even necessarily should be overriding `equals` here. Whether or not to override `equals` is a design decision. For example, maybe you want to implement some inventory for each scout, and they are able to carry two of the same type of weapon in the inventory at the same time. If you've overridden `equals` to consider two equivalent weapons as being the same, how do you tell them apart? What you actually seem to want here is some way to tell different *kinds* of weapons apart. Either just by checking their names, or with some kind of e.g. enum.

Comment: @Radiodef I just want it so Scouts can only upgrade and use certain weapons from the HashMap of Weapons. (think of the HashMap as an armoury) So the Scout is restricted on what weapons they can use from the armoury. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please implement `.equals()` method in Ranged class.

Also, the if condition in `rangedUpgrade(Ranged ranged)` that you have put is terminated on the same line.

Please modify the code of this method as:

```
public void rangedUpgrade(Ranged ranged) {       
        if (ranged.equals(WeaponList.getRanged("Shotgun"))){       
            this.ranged = ranged; 
            points = points + ranged.getWeaponPoints();
        } else 
            System.out.println("Can not have this weapon");
        }  
}
```

Comment: Okay, give me a few minutes

Comment: Thank you very much, also may i ask if a switch statement would work for mulitple conditions of different Weapons from the HashMap?

Comment: Yeah, you can use switch statements as well if you have multiple conditions.

Comment: Okay would that be something like switch(ranged)? I havn't really used them much before.

Comment: I tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet, sorry.

Comment: It would be on a string e.g. swithch(ranged.getName())

Comment: Okay i'll give it a go, do you mind if i message you if i have trouble? And thanks again.

Comment: Please post new questions if you have any trouble. Tag me in the question comments so that I get notifications. I would be happy to help.

Comment: Okay, I'll consider it. Although I always fear I'll be flagged down, and lose the abilty to ask questions. (Like I have before)